# Python, using multiprocess function outside class to get text for Qlabel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5

Im having wierd problem with geting temp data from API do QLabel that is in differend Class then data fetching function.Funkcion that fetches data from API uses http and multiprocess to speed up data gathering.
But When I run this Qlabel is getting blank text
Can You help me with that?
I think that multiprocess will be best for async data fetching, and that will not freez my whole app.

Here is my code

```
@pyqtSlot(str)
def temp_pobierz(id):
    call1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=temp_pobierz2, args=(id,), name='temp_pobierz2')
    call1.start()

@pyqtSlot(str)
def temp_pobierz2(id):
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    top_level_url = "http://" + config['NETWORK']['IP'] + ":8060/api/xml/device/" + (id) + "/state"
    # create an authorization handler
    try:
        p = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        p.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)
        auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        result = opener.open(top_level_url)
        messages = result.read()
        xml2 = messages.decode('utf-8')
        mydoc = minidom.parseString(xml2)
        items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('state')[0]
        temp = (items.firstChild.data).strip()
        print(temp)
        return temp
    except IOError as e:
        print(e)
        return "0.00"
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 30, 500, 500)
        self.top = 0
        self.left = 0
        self.width = 1024
        self.height = 600
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.init_ui()
        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.strona_temperatury = StronaTemperaturyOkno(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.strona_temperatury)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.strona_temperatury)

class StronaTemperatury(object):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def strona_temperatury(self):

        self.button = QPushButton('Wróć',self)
        self.button.move(900,550)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)

        self.dwor_lb = QLabel("Na zewnątrz", self)
        self.dwor_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.salon_lb = QLabel("Salon", self)
        self.salon_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.biuro_lb = QLabel("Biuro", self)
        self.biuro_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.jadalnia_lb = QLabel("Jadalnia", self)
        self.jadalnia_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.wejscie_lb = QLabel("Wejście główne", self)
        self.wejscie_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.kuchnia_lb = QLabel("Kuchnia", self)
        self.kuchnia_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.pokoj_tesciowej_lb = QLabel("Pokój teściowej", self)
        self.pokoj_tesciowej_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.pokoj_lilki_lb = QLabel("Pokój Lilki", self)
        self.pokoj_lilki_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.wc_parter_lb = QLabel("WC Parter", self)
        self.wc_parter_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.sypialnia_lb = QLabel("Sypialnia", self)
        self.sypialnia_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.wc_pietro_lb = QLabel("WC Piętro", self)
        self.wc_pietro_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)
        self.przysienek_lb = QLabel("Przysienek", self)
        self.przysienek_tp = QLabel("0.00", self)

        self.dwor_lb.move(50,20)
        self.dwor_tp.move(150,20)
        self.salon_lb.move(50,50)
        self.salon_tp.move(150,50)
        self.biuro_lb.move(50,80)
        self.biuro_tp.move(150,80)
        self.jadalnia_lb.move(50,110)
        self.jadalnia_tp.move(150,110)
        self.wejscie_lb.move(50,140)
        self.wejscie_tp.move(150,140)
        self.kuchnia_lb.move(50,170)
        self.kuchnia_tp.move(150,170)
        self.pokoj_tesciowej_lb.move(50,200)
        self.pokoj_tesciowej_tp.move(150,200)
        self.pokoj_lilki_lb.move(50,230)
        self.pokoj_lilki_tp.move(150,230)
        self.wc_parter_lb.move(50,260)
        self.wc_parter_tp.move(150,260)
        self.sypialnia_lb.move(50,290)
        self.sypialnia_tp.move(150,290)
        self.wc_pietro_lb.move(50,320)
        self.wc_pietro_tp.move(150,320)
        self.przysienek_lb.move(50,350)
        self.przysienek_tp.move(150,350)

        self.salon_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("47"))
        #self.dwor_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("49"))
        #self.biuro_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("110"))
        #self.jadalnia_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("19"))
        #self.wejscie_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("132"))
        #self.kuchnia_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("50"))
        #self.pokoj_tesciowej_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("113"))
        #self.pokoj_lilki_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("111"))
        #self.wc_parter_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("21"))
        #self.sypialnia_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("114"))
        #self.wc_pietro_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("112"))
        #self.przysienek_tp.setText(temp_pobierz("20"))

class StronaTemperaturyOkno(QWidget, StronaTemperatury):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StronaTemperaturyOkno, self).__init__(parent)
        self.strona_temperatury()
```

thanks for your help